# `print(x)` not giving same output as `x`

Tags: r, data.table

At the R console, I expected that `print(x)` will always give the same output as `x`. I had always assumed that `print` is used by the console to actually do the printing for everything. But there is an extra NULL here from `print`:

```
library(data.table)

print(data.table(1)[0])
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: V1
# NULL                                          # why is this 'NULL' printed here?

data.table(1)[0]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: V1
                                              # .. but no 'NULL' here?
```

This sample data is created by the `data.table` package, but I think the general question still applies even when not using `data.table`: what function/method is used to print return values at the console?

```
# R --vanilla  # R version 3.2.3
```

Comment: Please report it as a bug on github.

Comment: Doing that now @eddi . You meant a bug report with `data.table` for their print method, yes?. A number of answers (including my own, which I wrote after further experiments) suggest that `data.table`'s `print` method *should* return invisibly, but it actually returns visibly.

Comment: yep, it should return invisibly

Comment: just submitted a [bug report here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1852)

Comment: See update. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 8):

Update :

The fix has just been merged in v1.10.5. Thanks to Michael Chirico.

After running:

```
install.packages('data.table', type = 'source',
                 repos = 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table')
```

It will work as expected:

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.10.5 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2017-05-18 00:04:56 UTC; travis
#   The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors):  https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
#   Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and  browseVignettes("data.table")
#   Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com

print(data.table(1)[0])
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: V1

data.table(1)[0]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: V1
```

---

It might be because the `print` method for `data.table` is doing the wrong thing. Print methods are expected to return *invisibly*. But I suspect `data.table:::print.data.table` is returning *visibly*.

*(Update: I've just submitted [a bug report to data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1852). Apologies to them if I've analyzed this incorrectly! )*

From `?print`:

> ‘print’ prints its argument and returns it invisibly (via ‘invisible(x)’).

Here is a tiny demo of what might be happening:

```
> x=list()
> class(x) <- 'X'
> print.X <- function(x) { print("I am printing"); return(1729); }
> x
[1] "I am printing"
> print(x)
[1] "I am printing"
[1] 1729
```

Note how typing `x` on its own simply prints the text, but no number. But typing `print(x)` causes the number to be printed also.

Then, if I arrange for this print method to return *invisibly* as follows:

```
> print.X <- function(x) { print("I am printing"); return(invisible(1729)); }
```

.. then `print(x)` gives the expected output

```
> print(x)
[1] "I am printing"
```

So, when you type `x` at the console, the console does call `print` on your behalf and ignores the return value from `print` (which may be *visible*). But if you type `print(x)`, then the return value of `print` will be printed if it is visible.

---

The `?print` documentation is a bit misleading I think. `print` methods are *supposed* to return their argument and are *supposed* to do so invisibly, but these rules are not enforced

Comment: Thanks to @RHertel for pointing me towards the docs that `print` returns invisibly. Or, in my interpretation, *should* return invisibly and that implementors of `print` methods are expected to return invisibly

Comment: Maybe this test is interesting, too: `print.Y <- function() { print("I am printing"); invisible(1729) }; print(print.Y())`.

Comment: There is a difference in the sources, indeed. The last line of `print.data.frame` is `invisible(x)` while `data.table:::print.data.table` has `print(toprint, right = TRUE, quote = quote)` and `invisible()`, so the latter is returning `NULL`. However, I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. I remember some issues with `knitr` when updating a `data.table` object by reference.

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to the return value of print.

From `?print`:

> ‘print’ prints its argument and returns it *invisibly* (via ‘invisible(x)’).

So `print` has a return value, which happens to be `NULL` in this case. On the other hand, typing a variable in the console creates an output, but it does not return anything, and `NULL` is not displayed.

Comment: After doing some experiments, I suspect that `cat(capture.output(x),'\n',sep='')` is the most direct way, within a script, to print `x` in the same manner (i.e. respecting visibility) as one gets at the console. Is this true? It seems a bit complex

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I assume that you are right, but I am not certain. Maybe we can wait and see if other answers will be posted that will shed further light on the matter. Interesting question, by the way.

Comment: In the example in the question, I get `NULL` only if I use `print`. Yet you say that `print` should return an *invisible* NULL. In that case, why do we see a *visible* `NULL` in this call to print? Maybe `print` methods are *supposed* to return invisibly, but the `data.table` `print` method returns *visibly*?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid If you have a function that returns an invisible value, then the return value becomes visible by wrapping that function into `print()`. I can add an example if you want. Anyway, this is what makes me suspect that the return value plays a role here. I have formulated my answer in a prudent manner because I have the same doubts that you expressed... It sounds like it should not be visible, on the other hand `print` makes invisible returns visible.. I admit that I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The print method called depends on the class of the object. As such there is a print.table, print.data.frame,print.factor,etc, each of these has a different function that determines what is printed.

Try this

```
x<-NULL
print.data.frame(x)
print.table(x)
```

Have a look at the functions

```
print.data.frame
print.table
```

You'll see what is returned is different depending on what S3 method of print is called and there are many ways to print.

The exact print you are calling depends on the class of your data.table object.

It also means you can create your own custom S3 method for printing by assigning a custom class to your object and creating a custom print function

```
class(object)<-"customclass"

print.customclass<-function(object,...){
   body of function
}

print(object)
```

Comment: If the use doesn't explicitly type `print`, then how does the text get printed to the screen? I assumed the console always called `print` "on the user's behalf" so to speak, but the example in my question suggests otherwise

Comment: On another note, I wasn't really asking about methods. Regardless of which method is used, why is there an extra `NULL` in the example in the question?